# Python Selenium not able to locate proper element for uploading a file

Tags: python, selenium

HTML code for "choose a file" button

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$InputFile" type="file" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_InputFile" class="ms-fileinput ms-fullWidth" size="35" onfocus="ResetSpFormOnSubmitCalled();" onchange="CheckAssetLibMediaExtension()" title="Choose a file">
```

Python Code

```
choose_file= browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_InputFile')
choose_file.send_keys(file_path)
```

But this is not working for me.

Comment: HTML CODE FOR BUTTON<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$InputFile" type="file" 
id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_InputFile" class="ms-fileinput ms-fullWidth" 
size="35" onfocus="ResetSpFormOnSubmitCalled();" onchange="CheckAssetLibMediaExtension()" title="Choose a file">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some technology stacks will autogenerate the id's for elements and looking at how messy that id is it might be one of those. I would recommend using a different selector because of this.

This may work better for you if there is only one file upload button:

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input.ms-fileinput')`